# Conformal transformation

Tags: conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, quasiconformal-maps

This is a problem in Volkovyskii's book. I have a little difficulty finding the right result.

Who can show me how to find the conformal mapping how affects the exterior of the parabola $y^2=2px,\,\,(p>0)$ (that is the domain bounded by this parabola and not containing its focus) onto the right-hand half-plane?

Comment: Consider where $\sqrt {p - 2 z}$ maps the parabola $z = t^2/(2 p) + i t$.